# SQL Join tables and concat names from table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql 5.5 I´ve three tables like:

employee

```
ID | firstname | lastname
-------------------------
1  | John      | Doe
2  | Henry     | Fonda
```

employee_projects

```
ID | employee_id | project_id
------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 1         | 2
3  | 2         | 3
```

projects

```
ID | name 
----------------------
1  | house   
2  | cottage 
3  | castle
```

**How do I JOIN employee over emloyee_project with projects that I get as result:**

```
ID | firstname | lastname | projects
-------------------------------------
1  | John      | Doe      | house, cottage
2  | Henry     | Fonda    | castle
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables together and use group_concat to aggregate the rows into csv values.

```
select e.*, t.projects
from employee e 
left join (
    select ep.employee_id, group_concat(p.name) as projects
    from employee_projects ep
    join projects p on ep.project_id = p.id
    group by ep.employee_id
    ) t on e.id = t.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select  e.id
,       e.firstname
,       e.lastname
,       group_concat(p.name) as projects
from    employee e
left join
        employee_projects ep
on      e.id = ep.employee_id
left join
        projects p
on      ep.project_id = p.id
group by
        e.id
,       e.firstname
,       e.lastname
```